# yaml-cpp unresolved external symbol error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, yaml, linker-errors

I'm trying to build a solution in Visual Studio 2017. And I get these errors:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: UA_Parser, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>UaParserTest.cpp
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class YAML::Node __cdecl YAML::LoadFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?LoadFile@YAML@@YA?AVNode@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl YAML::InvalidNode::~InvalidNode(void)" (??1InvalidNode@YAML@@UEAA@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl YAML::Exception::~Exception(void)" (??1Exception@YAML@@UEAA@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl YAML::RepresentationException::~RepresentationException(void)" (??1RepresentationException@YAML@@UEAA@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl YAML::BadConversion::~BadConversion(void)" (??1BadConversion@YAML@@UEAA@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl YAML::BadSubscript::~BadSubscript(void)" (??1BadSubscript@YAML@@UEAA@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class YAML::detail::node & __cdecl YAML::detail::memory::create_node(void)" (?create_node@memory@detail@YAML@@QEAAAEAVnode@23@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl YAML::detail::node_data::convert_to_map(class std::shared_ptr<class YAML::detail::memory_holder>)" (?convert_to_map@node_data@detail@YAML@@AEAAXV?$shared_ptr@Vmemory_holder@detail@YAML@@@std@@@Z)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "private: void __cdecl YAML::detail::node_data::insert_map_pair(class YAML::detail::node &,class YAML::detail::node &)" (?insert_map_pair@node_data@detail@YAML@@AEAAXAEAVnode@23@0@Z)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class YAML::detail::node_iterator_base<class YAML::detail::node> __cdecl YAML::detail::node_data::end(void)" (?end@node_data@detail@YAML@@QEAA?AV?$node_iterator_base@Vnode@detail@YAML@@@23@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: class YAML::detail::node_iterator_base<class YAML::detail::node> __cdecl YAML::detail::node_data::begin(void)" (?begin@node_data@detail@YAML@@QEAA?AV?$node_iterator_base@Vnode@detail@YAML@@@23@XZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl YAML::detail::node_data::set_scalar(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?set_scalar@node_data@detail@YAML@@QEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl YAML::detail::node_data::set_null(void)" (?set_null@node_data@detail@YAML@@QEAAXXZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl YAML::detail::node_data::mark_defined(void)" (?mark_defined@node_data@detail@YAML@@QEAAXXZ)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > YAML::detail::node_data::empty_scalar" (?empty_scalar@node_data@detail@YAML@@2V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)
1>UaParser.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl YAML::detail::memory_holder::merge(class YAML::detail::memory_holder &)" (?merge@memory_holder@detail@YAML@@QEAAXAEAV123@@Z)
1>C:\bmetric\C++ Projects\UA_Parser\x64\Release\UA_Parser.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 16 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "UA_Parser.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I have a feeling they can be solved by linking, but I am not sure what to link (the precise folder).

So far, I have built the yaml-cpp as described on github. Also, I have added the `..\yaml-cpp\include` folder in the `Additional Include Directories` from `Configuration Properties >> C/C++ >> General` and tried to include in the `Additional Library Directories` (Linker) various folders, unsuccessfully.

Never used YAML before. And I don't link stuff often.

Comment: You do not link against a folder, but against a library file. `Additional Library Directories` only tells Visual Studio where to *look* for the libraries you want to link against. You need to add the library created by compiling yaml-cpp to the linker input.

Comment: @flyx, please be more precise.

Comment: If I knew Visual Studio, I would write an answer instead of just commenting.

Comment: `I have a feeling they can be solved by linking, but I am not sure what to link` - You need to link with `.lib` file. Find this file in the `yaml-cpp` tree (the file is created during building `yaml-cpp` project). Then follow regular steps for linking something in Visual Studio.

Comment: I do not have such a file.

Comment: Last lines from yaml building:
`-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.11.25503/bin/Hostx86/x64/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: C:/Program Files/Python36/python.exe (found version "3.6.2")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Program Files/cpplibs/yaml-cpp/build`

Comment: This output is from CMake. It tells you that it generated the build files (probably a solution of project file for Visual Studio). It has *not* compiled `yaml-cpp` – you need to do that by opening the solution / project file in Visual Studio and compile it.

Comment: Embarrassed to have missed that step. Anyway, after I build it. I have a file `libyaml-cppmd.lib` to which I link through `Linker` >> `Additional Library Directories`. But this does not help at all. I get the same errors.

Comment: You need to add `libyaml-cppmd.lib` to the linker *Input* and the containing directory to the `Additional Library Directories`.

Comment: Thank you, @flyx! That solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the unresolved external symbols errors because I was including `#include <yaml-cpp/node/node.h>`, which is what Resharper recommended me(and it's is correct 99.9% of the time). In this case it's a wrong header and what I should have been including is: `#include <yaml-cpp/yaml.h>`.

I fixed my includes in my files and it built successfully.